# Sawmills vs other mills

Tags: meaning, etymology, differences, ambiguity

A flour mill makes flour.

A paper mill makes paper.

A puppy mill breeds puppies.

But a sawmill makes... saws?  No - it *uses* saws to make wood products.

Can anyone explain the etymology or language quirks in play here?

Comment: Did you look up the definition of the word "mill"? It doesn't "make" anything.  Start here to fill in the gaps and bring back any specific question you might have after that: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mill

Comment: The existence of a pattern does not mean all similar-looking compounds should necessarily follow the same pattern: *snowball*, *meatball*, *hairball*, but *football*, *blackball*, *screwball*, *buckyball*, *cannonball*.

Comment: Note that only a bitch can *make* puppies (for the time being), and the mill only *breeds* puppies in a figurative sense.

Comment: And did the mills that Blake mentioned in "Jerusalem" *produce* dark satanics? And if so, where did they all go?

Comment: So why is it you park in a driveway and drive on a parkway?  (Hint:  It's English!)

Comment: "If olive oil is made from olives, then what is baby oil made from?"

Comment: @sumelic From babies, of course.  When all the oil has been extracted, the remainder is ground up to make baby powder.

Comment: Obligatory: https://youtu.be/_zCO4j4MrxE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to trace the usage here, partly because the two words "saw" (the instrument) and "mill" (the building or device) are very old, stretching back to the beginnings of the language about one thousand years ago.  During its lifetime the word "saw" has had a propensity to make combinations, in the words of the *OED* attributive (*saw-blade*), objective (*saw-grinder*), and "similative" (*saw-toothed*).

The word "sawmill" isn't that old, dating to 1553 as *sawe mylles* (again, per the *OED*).  The same construct appears in our sister language:  *Sägemühle* is the German word.

But the construct isn't as quirky as you may think.  The resulting product isn't the only thing that attaches to the device.  Sometimes it's the powering agency -- "water mill," "windmill"; sometimes, the raw input -- "silk mill," "corn mill"; sometimes, the process -- "rolling mill,"flatting mill."

Comment: Thanks. Make sense especially considering "windmill", since windmills *use* the wind to do other things, they don't *make* the wind.